# app signal gem send error to app signal without a crash request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using appsignal gem to track if there is an error processing in my app.

This case i do call external API using faraday.

```ruby
def truck_information(req_params)
      response = @conn.post('truck/info') do |req|
        req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        req.body = req_params
      end

      return JSON.parse(response.body) if response_successful?(response)

      response_error(response)
end

def response_successful?(response)
    response.status == 200
end

def response_error(response)
      err = NctError, "Code: #{response.status}, response: #{response.body}"
      Appsignal.set_error(err)

      raise NctError, I18n.t('error_messages.ppob.server_error')
end
```

my truck_information is used to call external api. and if success i will parse it to json. but if error i will call response_error method parser to create custom class error (NctError) and i want to send to appsignal to show the error without breaking the application process.

But when i was tested it, it doesn't send to appsignal. How to do send error to appsignal, even if it doesn't crash a request? because i need to track the error.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [Appsignal.send_error](https://docs.appsignal.com/ruby/instrumentation/exception-handling.html#appsignal-send_error)

```rb
Appsignal.send_error(err)
```

If above doesn't work either, then `set_error` and `send_error` may only work with `Exception`:

```rb
def response_error(response)
  raise NctError, I18n.t('error_messages.ppob.server_error')
rescue => e
  Appsignal.send_error(e) do |transaction|
    transaction.params = { code: response.status, response: response.body }
  end
end
```

Comment: i forget my reason to raise NctError after my intention to send appsignal message. The raise NctError with translation, it supposed to be sent to our API consumer as error message. but if i did rescue, does it still send the error message to our consumer api?

Comment: `raise` just raise error, it doesn't  send the error message to consumer API normally. You could send  the error message within `rescue` i.e.  `render json: { msg: I18n.t('error_messages.ppob.server_error')}, status: response.status`, it depends on your code logic.

Comment: my bad again, i did catch error my application controller, so it will send response json to consumer API